# Magento 2 multi store with ubuntu and apache

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3, multidomain, apache2

I have magento instance running on **8090 port**. I have created an another store call **store2** I followed all the steps and also change base url and added store code with base url as per this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html)

My virtual host file is below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        ServerName http://192.168.1.179:8090/

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          http://192.168.1.179:8090/store2/
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "store2"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
 </VirtualHost>
```

My index.php is below.

```
<?php

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$customstore = array(
    'http://192.168.1.179:8090/store2'=>'store2' // Website, Store or Storeview Code

    );
if(isset($customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]))
    $websitecode = $customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($websitecode) ? $websitecode : '';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';//use website or store or view 
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

but my **http://192.168.1.179:8090/store2** returns 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new directory for store2 and copy the .htaccess and index.php into that new directory. Then update /store2/index.php to set the website code and update the line `require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';` to go up one directory. This way when you hit http://192.168.1.179:8090/store2 it will start at your new directory and index.php file. You can also symlink media, static, errors, etc from your store2 directory back to your /var/html/www media, static, and error directories. I believe you will also need to update your DocumentRoot in your virtual host from your example above.

Also, if you don't have a home page specified for the new store view it will display a 404 as well.